# lowestCommonAncestor for neo4j

Tags: neo4j

How do I correctly use the `lowestCommonAncestor` algorithm in a cypher query for a 2.0 implementation of `neo4j`?

```
start read=node:readID('readid:"HWI-ST884:57:1:1101:13989:75421#0"') match read-[r]->gi where r.bitscore > "35" with gi match lca=lowestCommonAncestor(gi) return lca;
SyntaxException: Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, node labels, a relationship pattern, ',', USING, WHERE, CREATE, DELETE, SET, REMOVE, RETURN, WITH, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 151)
"start read=node:readID('readid:"HWI-ST884:57:1:1101:13989:75421#0"') match read-[r]->gi where r.bitscore > "35" with gi match lca=lowestCommonAncestor(gi) return lca"
                                                                                                                                                        ^
```

[See Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/1.9.2/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/ancestor/AncestorsUtil.java#AncestorsUtil.lowestCommonAncestor%28java.util.List,org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipExpander%29)

Comment: I'm not aware of a `lowestCommonAncester` function in Cypher. Where have you found that?

Comment: I'm curious if it is.... And if not how can I use it? See the link I provided? @StefanArmbruster

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use the lowestCommonAncestor function you're referring to is through Java API. You can e.g. write a [unmanaged extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) that uses this function internally. At the moment this function is not exposed to `Cypher`.

> Please be aware that AncestorUtil is *not* part the public API of Neo4j - which means any change can happen from one version to another.

Comment: Thanks @StefanArmbruster, on a sad note, it looks like I'll have to learn JAVA to be able to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use regular cypher to find the same?

```
MATCH (lca)<-[:REL*]-(n)
WHERE id(n) in {ids}
WITH lca, count(distinct n) as leaves
WHERE leaves = length({ids})
RETURN lca
```

Comment: yea, i could do that, @michael how do you parse a list of ids in this case into the query?

Comment: I adapted the query but i still cant get the `where leaves = length({ids})` part working

`start n=node:readID('readid:"HWI-    ST884:124:D0G92ACXX:1:1101:10761:149051"') 
match (n)-[r]->(tax)-[:childof*]->(common)
where r.bitscore > "35"
with common, count(DISTINCT tax) as leaves
where leaves > 30
return common,labels(common),leaves;`

Comment: in the graph object i'm exploring, it begins with one node and spreads out to many nodes in the middle before it starts converging again to 1 , so in the example michael gave, its not exactly suitable.